# What data type should I use to save correctly this data is PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a database in PostgreSQL. When I save the data in the db, the datatype of (`name`, `password`, `email`, etc...) are `character` and the `length` is 100.
So, all is ok! but when I make a request from NodeJS to PostgreSQL, I receive this:

```
name: 'John Madzukich                                 '
password: 'd92363c27a                                   '
email: 'ct48@yoh.com                                   '
```

and to match the password with, (for example) a req.body I have to do this:

```
    if(req.body.password == datadb.password.trim()){
      // code 
    }
```

The question is: what data type should I use to the DB returns the data with all that blank spaces? maybe just `text`, `character varying`...

There is a photo: [image]

Comment: If you try to use that email and password, Are you able to login? If you can't probably your problem is on the save the data to postgre and not in the response.

Comment: @Gi1ber7 that is exactly my problem. I control the data with  .trim()

Comment: I kind of confuse; do you need the blank spaces? Why area you saving blank spaces? It looks like a bad design approach...

Comment: @Gi1ber7 i don't need that blank spaces, when I put the info with a form the DB save with that blank spaces

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification.  Then, char(length) or text will do the job...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all these spaces, do you? All they do is waste space in the database.

PostgreSQL has the data type `character` because the SQL standard says so, but it is a pretty useless data type, and you usually are much happier if you don't use it.

You should probably use `text` or, if there is a reason in the application to limit the length, `character varying`.

Comment: I don't need that blank spaces.
I will try with character varying